# Doctrine 2: doctrine:fixtures:load unexpected warning

Tags: doctrine-orm, fixtures, nelmio-alice

I'm loading a yaml file using nelmio/alice bundle.

There's a weird behavior when including the second entity of a many to many relationship. when running the load command it throws a warning:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]   Warning:
>   copy(http://lorempixel.com/640/480/?35984): failed to open stream:
>   Impossible to estabilish connection..

yaml file code is the following:

```
AppBundle\Entity\ComponentInstance:
    componentInstance_{1..30}:
      componentCode: <componentInstanceCode()>
      componentId: <numberBetween(1,50)>
      sectionInstance: '@sectionInstance_*'
      date: <datetime()>
      images: '@componentImage_{1..2}'

AppBundle\Entity\ComponentImage:
    componentImage_{1..4}:
      imageName: <name()>
      imagePath: <image()>
      imageAlt: <text()>
      width: <numberBetween(100,500)>
      height: <numberBetween(100,500)>
      components: '@componentInstance_{1..2}'
```

As I put comments on the ComponentImage part it works without any problem. 
There is no track of that url inside the whole project.

the `image()` function is the following:

```
public function images()
    {
      $genera = [
          '/images/color_pencils.jpg',
          '/images/half_color_pencils.jpg',
          '/images/rainbow_wood.bmp',
          '/images/color_smoke.jpg'
      ];
      $key = array_rand($genera);
      return $genera[$key];
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: probably some entitylistener on ComponentImage?

Comment: could [this](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle/issues/44#issuecomment-191300698) can help?

Comment: thank you for you comments @Matteo
the problem was another, way sillier. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came out being a mix of a couple of elements.

I made a typo caling

```
imagePath: <image()>
```

instead of `<images()>`

The second, and more confusing point was that `<image()>` is reserved keyword of nelmio/alice bundle which automatically generates an url to http://lorempixel.com

by calling the correct function it loads the data correctly